# Google maps api results into div or table

Tags: google-maps

Hy, i use Google Maps Api V3 and i would to print the result into a table or div .
In the example, the result will show into a select with this code:

Javascript

```
function createOption(name, distance, num) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = num;
      option.innerHTML = "" + name + "";
      locationSelect.appendChild(option);
    }
```

all code : http://jsfiddle.net/dgqWm/1/

Comment: How do you get you results - fusion table or smth else?

Comment: i get the reseults from xml generated from php phpsqlsearch_genxml

Answer (score 1):

In case you have server side (PHP) you could simply write HTML element (dropdown list) on server. Ugly example:

```
echo "<select id='locationSelect' onchange='OnLocationChanged();'>";
foreach( $entries as $num => $name )
{
    echo sprintf("<option value='%d'>%s</option>", $num, $name);
}
echo "</select>";
```